# nifi error flow not working unless two files in queue

Tags: apache, apache-nifi

This is for nifi 1.3.

I have an executeScript Processor which is connected to a putSplunk Processor through a failure flow. I am doing some testing so currently I  make the executeScript Processor fail which causes a flow file to go into the failure flow. The flow file seems to sit in the queue and is not processed or at least not processed fully by the putSplunk processor. If I stop the processor group containing these processors and then start again while a 
flow file is stuck in the failure flow queue then the flow file is pushed through and processed in the putSplunk Processor. I have this already running in nifi 1.1 and I do not get this issue. What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, just in case anyone runs into this. Seems like it has something to do with the scheduler while I could set the putSplunk Timer to high number of seconds in 1.1 it seems that in 1.3 I need to set the number of seconds to 0 or a low amount of time and it seems to work now. Maybe it does not run for the first time until the number of seconds specified or there are multiple flow files queued. Success and Failure are terminated so that does not matter.